# Bootstrap variable column height and count without breaking flow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the actual project there are a bunch of boxes. We are using bootstraps grid and column system so the number displayed horizontally changes based on window size. This works wonderfully as long as all the boxes are equal height.

In this little example I have 11 boxes with one that's taller than the others. How can I, without using bootstrap rows or js, have this not break the flow of boxes? I provided a couple images to demonstrate what I mean.

CSS

```
.box{
    border: solid 1px black;
    height: 200px;
}
.taller{
    height: 300px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 box"></div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 box"></div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 box"></div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 box taller"></div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 box"></div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 box"></div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 box"></div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 box"></div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 box"></div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 box"></div>
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 box"></div>
</div>
```

What I want:

[image: good]

What I am getting:

[image: bad]

Comment: Well, i couldn't see your images so i'm not certain what you're trying to do and what it's actually doing.  However, one thought did come to mind: try to wrap the boxes "per-row" with another sized div. For example, <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that sadly isn't what I need.

Answer (score 1):

A literal solution would be to put clear: left; on the 7th box. Not sure if this satisfies your criteria.

MasonryJS is a good JS solution to this issue.

Comment: That will only work for a specific window size. What if the second box was the taller box and the viewport smaller? Then the 5th box might need the clear. Though I do agree that a JS solution might be in order even though the OP is looking for a non-JS solution.

Comment: I think you might be on to something!! I'm gonna try using @media in combination with child selectors on this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a suggestion from @key I was able to combine his clear solution with CSS media selectors and solve it.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .col-sm-4:nth-child(3n+1){
        clear: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .col-md-3:nth-child(4n+1){
        clear: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-2:nth-child(6n+1){
        clear: left;
    }
}
```